# Looking for science fiction short story collection from 1970's

Tags: story-identification

I bought a collection of short stories in about 1978, probably used, and have been looking for it again for years.

One of the stories was of an alien who comes to earth and eats everything in the restaurant at an all you can eat buffet to take the food back his planet.

Another was about a society where the government makes everybody equal by having smart people wear gongs that interrupt their thoughts and ballet dancers wearing sand bags. Does anybody know this collection? Thank you!

Comment: The second story you mention is "Harrison Bergeron" by Kurt Vonnegut. If you look it up on ISFDB (follow the URL at the bottom of this comment), you will see it's been reprinted *many* times. I don't know which of those anthologies also contains the other story you mention; offhand, I'm not recognizing that one from your description. That's why I make this a comment instead of an "Answer." http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41335

Answer (score 16):

The first story is [All You Can Eat](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?68025) by Harvey L. Bilker and Audrey L. Bilker.

> As the story progresses the alien continues to eat prodigious amounts
> of food, to the dismay of the establishment's other customers and
> eventually the restaurant owner himself. Eventually the alien reveals
> that he hails from a distant planet that has been wrecked by
> pollution, and now its inhabitants have to send agents across the
> galaxy to consume and "kinergize" food back to their starving
> population.
> <sub><sup>[Review: Children of Infinity](http://dreamingaboutotherworlds.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/review-children-of-infinity-by-roger.html)</sup></sub>

The second story is [Harrison Bergeron](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41335) by Kurt Vonnegut Jr.

> It is the year 2081, and all people have been made 'equal' through the
> use of physical and mental handicaps. The United States Constitution
> mandates this equality in the 211th, 212th, and 213th Amendments, and
> the law is enforced by Diana Moon Glampers, the Handicapper General.
>
> <sub><sup>[GradeSaver: Harrison Bergeron Summary](http://www.gradesaver.com/kurt-vonnegut-short-stories/study-guide/summary-harrison-bergeron)</sup></sub>

While 'Harrison Bergeron' has been collected endlessly, 'All You Can Eat' appears to have been collected in only one anthology; [Children of Infinity](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?435674).